# Using For Loop in Selenium - Web Testing

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, nested-loops

I'm trying to automate our testing for a website that has individual pages for each location.

This is the code I have tried but it is giving me a stale element error (Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document).

The concept is this:
Open the store directory page -> Click on the state -> Click on the cities in that state -> click on the stores in that city -> repeat

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = 'https://example.com'

driver.get(url)

print(driver.title)

time.sleep(5)

states = ['Alaska', 'Arizona', 'California']

# - clicking on the state
for state in states:
    search_states = driver.find_element_by_link_text(state)
    search_states.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    # - click on the city
    search_cities = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Directory-listLinkText')
    for city in search_cities:
        time.sleep(2)
        city.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        stores = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Teaser-titleLink')
        time.sleep(2)

        # - click on the store
        for store in stores:
            store.click()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What you want to do is get the length of the items you want to loop and then index them while using driver.back on each store and then driver.back on the city.

Comment: can you show the code for one of the loops?

Answer (score 1):

This should go to each store in a city.

```
stores = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Teaser-titleLink')
for i in range(len(stores)):
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Teaser-titleLink')[i].click()
    driver.back()
driver.back()
```

You could also use xpath and use the index

Comment: what is the difference between using for i in range and my method?

Comment: would you be able to show the whole code? I'm getting an index out of range error when trying to do it your way - thank you

Comment: When you leave a page you have to get the elements again or they will become stale.